# How to modify or write new custom actions for TFS

Tags: c#, .net, tfs, project-management

There are various built-in state transition actions available in TFS. There is a lot of documentation available on what is action and when and how it works. However, I've not been able to find any documentation that helps me write new or modify existing actions.

For example, I've a custom field for work item 'Task'. Its a 'Due Date' of the task that automatically gets set when the state of task is changed to 'Active'. I now want a way to either modify the state transition action `Microsoft.VSTS.Actions.StartWork` which is already being called or write a new action to set the value of 'Due Date' of the task calculated based on `Original Estimate` and `Activated Date`.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, calculated fields such as this are not supported as hinted [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms404857.aspx) but there is a [feature request](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio-2015/suggestions/3595615-support-calculated-fields-in-tfs) for it

There's an 'Improved Process Customization' feature coming as listed on the [Features Timeline](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/news/release-archive-vso.aspx) but I can't see this specific feature listed. Shame.

How about using the TFS API to update the field after it's transitioned into the 'active' state? You could use alerts by creating an alert to call a custom web service which in turn uses the TFS API to update it. It would be fairly instant but it's a long-winded approach and a lot of hassle, depends how important this is to you I guess